# Dockerfile: Using ADD file as the first line in your dockerfile instead of FROM

Tags: docker, dockerfile

The Docker documentation states:

> The FROM instruction initializes a new build stage and sets the Base Image for subsequent >instructions. As such, a valid Dockerfile must start with a FROM instruction.

[source](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from)

However the Dockerfile for httpd starts with:

> ADD file:51108b89c70ce0773c897be520c84454660f38b84ba556da49c7fe77e5d52416 in /

[source](https://hub.docker.com/layers/httpd/library/httpd/latest/images/sha256-548248173d4a6633c730a1ad8030c2f2d7dc86cdff3b6e0f5d44e0e3137afdc9?context=explore)

The [official Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add) describes the ADD keyword, but it doesn't describe the syntax of `file:51108b89c70ce0773c897be520c84454660f38b84ba556da49c7fe77e5d52416`. What does `file:51108b89c70ce0773c897be520c84454660f38b84ba556da49c7fe77e5d52416` mean? Since it appears to be a SHA256, how can I see the contents of where the SHA256 hash points to? And is it no longer necessary for a Dockerfile to start with the `FROM` keyword?

Comment: `However the Dockerfile for httpd starts with:` No, it doesn't. https://github.com/docker-library/httpd/blob/master/2.4/Dockerfile

Comment: @tkausl thank you for pointing me to the Github repo. The Dockerfile on the Github repo shows different instructions compared to the Dockerfile on Dockerhub. Do you know why they differ?

Comment: They differ because the link to dockerhub doesn't show a Dockerfile, it shows the image's layers.

Comment: It's an HTML presentation of the `docker history` output, and starts from `ADD`ing a base Linux distribution tarball to a `FROM scratch` image.