# Meaning of hash after ADD file: in docker history

Tags: docker, docker-image

If I run `docker history --no-trunc IMAGE` on an image which was built from a Dockerfile like:

```
FROM scratch
ADD something.tar.xz /
...
```

I see the following under the `CREATED BY` column in the last line of the `docker history` output:

```
/bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:fb0755f94145d1e0a46167faf3b43dba3db9383f4c230217a500a65e01307e27 in /
```

The part after `file:` looks like a SHA256 hash of *something* but it doesn't match the SHA256 of...

- the file referenced in the Dockerfile (`something.tar.xz`)
- the name of that file or its full path at build time
- the layer digest or any other which I see in the output from any Docker ls/inspect/etc.

So my question is, purely out of interest, **what** is this the hash of?

### Related questions

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64572931/dockerfile-using-add-file-as-the-first-line-in-your-dockerfile-instead-of-from) is related but based on the misunderstanding that the `ADD file:...` is actually in the Dockerfile.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63823884/docker-image-layer-what-does-add-filesome-hash-in-mean) kind of implicitly asks my question but the closest to an answer is:

> I'm not sure there's a reliable way to translate from the host file or URL to the hash

So I want to explicitly ask the question of what the hash actually refers to, even though I fully understand that I cannot magically reconstitute any information from it about the original file which was `ADD`ed.

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing. I wonder if this is permissions-related. My guess is that the tarball gets exploded on disk and then _that's_ hashed (as a layer) and what makes it into the history. See https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/32816, but I can't immediately think about how to reproduce it.

Comment: Potentially relevant: https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/pkg/tarsum/tarsum.go -> https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/7b9275c0da707b030e62c96b679a976f31f929d3/pkg/tarsum/tarsum_spec.md